# Im creating simple function in typescript but it thrwos me syntax error why?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Im creating a simple function in type script but when i try to run the code in vsc it throws me with this error SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' why ?

[image]

Comment: Node.js cannot execute TypeScript code. You need to transpile it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're executing TypeScript with `node`. `node` executes JavaScript. TypeScript must first be transpiled into JavaScript with `tsc`.

See [TypeScript Tooling in 5 minutes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-tooling-in-5-minutes.html)